# ValueError when using pandas Groupby with aggregate function List

Tags: python, pandas, list, group-by

I have a dataset that I am trying to organize using the pandas function groupby. I am trying to groupby the column zip code and aggregate by list so that the values of the dataframe that are grouped form a new list

```
sheet1 = pd.read_excel(data, "Data")
other_columns = sheet1.loc[:, sheet1.dtypes!=np.float64]    
other_columns=other_columns.groupby("zip_code").agg(list).reset_index()
```

I want the code to be grouped by zip code, with each cell of grouped columns to be a list of the values. However, I am receiving this error message:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (75, 665), indices imply (74, 665)
```

Comment: whats in list ?

Comment: The lists include categories or strings

Comment: @minanmafi you should actually show the contents of `list` in your question